# How to display, "No Results Available If No record available in reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reportviewer

When we run our report using reportviewer, records are displayed successfully if found.

However, if no record found then it will display only header with all Fields.

Rather than display empty, we would like to display message "No results available at this time. Please check again later"

The code below obviously doesn't get the job done.

Any ideas what I need to modify in the code below to make this work?

```
Sub Run_Report(ByVal sel As String)
    ReportViewer1.Reset()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim params__p1(1) As ReportParameter
    which.Value = "U"
    Call Run_Report("")
    Select Case which.Value

        Case "U"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ObjectDataSource1.ID))
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "myTestResults.rdlc"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
            params_p1(0) = New ReportParameter("username", username.Text, False)
            params__p1(1) = New ReportParameter("email", email.Text, False)
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params__p1)
        Case Else
            lblMsg.Text = "No results available at this time. Please check again later"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using SSRS NoRowsMessage property.

On reports property, I entered **No Record found**

Now, if there is no record, the message, **No Record found** is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an expression inside your report to display something different when no rows are found. Here's a good starting point for the [expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251668%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you put data in your datasource (datatable or dataset), you can check if the datatable is empty or not as..

```
if ( DataTable.Rows.Count == 0 )  ->  set the TextObjext.Text = "No Record found".
```

Comment: not sure how to tie your code to mine.

Bazinga, I may be stupid but I don't see how that link helps me.